# Can't find ':' in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run wordpress with ssl through docker compose.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
    volumes: 
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:5-fpm-alpine
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$MYSQL_USER
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
  webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:1.15.12-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certbotdata:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - app-network
  certbot:
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbotdata:/etc/letsencrypt
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email info@domain.com--agree-tos --no-eff-email --force-renewal -d web.domain.com
volumes:
  wordpress:
  dbdata:
  certbotdata:
```

I get the following error:

```
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 49, column 1
could not find expected ':'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 50, column 1
```

It's the lines with 'volumes:' and 'wordpress:'.

When I leave out the cerbot service and volume, it works?!

What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried this Copy your code and past it to some online yml validator?

Comment: Check for spaces vs tabs, types of line endings, and delete lines you suspect are causing errors until you get a minimal working file and add back lines one at a time to find the error.